# Is sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu no longer signed?

Tags: apt, update-manager

I've been trying to simply update the default repos on a recently acquired Ubuntu 20 LTS workstation and these errors occur:

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
Err:2 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
Err:3 http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.79.180.254 80]
E: The repository 'http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It was working just fine yesterday, so I'm still wondering if some error occurred during the update of default packages.

Does anybody knows if the sg.archive site is working as intended (i.e. http://sg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu appears forbiden on my browser using both my work network and my mobile data network).

Alternatively, does anybody knows the fingerprint of those servers in case that is a problem with they keys at my end?

Thank you,

Amhed

Comment: Hey Karel,  you're right, I just realized that changing the Ubuntu server to canonical servers solves the issue. Thanks!
That said, do you know to whom I could address this problem within the maintainers of sg.archive? Being the closest server to my location I guess the installation process of any program will be much faster. Thanks again

Comment: Mirrors like sg.archive are volunteers. They come. They go. There are currently no less that eight other Singapore volunteer mirrors. See https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors for the complete current list.

Comment: That's quite interesting. Thanks for sharing